# ArcMap PYT toolbox open so slow every time starting new .mxd

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-toolbox

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

If I put this class (code below) in a empty PYT toolbox, it will take more than 10 seconds to open, everytime starting a new mxd.

So far I find the reason is the default value of featurelayer (GPFeatureLayer).

But a normal toolbox (.tbx) with a script in it, writing default value in parameter setting won't take this time to open toolbox.

[image: .tbx setting]

Therefore I hope to find a way to make my PYT toolbox open faster, and set datatype as GPFeatureLayer (not GPString as a temporary patch).

Here's how this happens.

```
class Export_Feature(object):
    def __init__(self):
            self.label = 'Output'
            self.description = 'pre-operate feature for FME'
            self.canRunInBackground = False
            self.category = 'IO'
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        params=[]

        ...

        param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName='OutputFeature',
            name='OutputFeature',
            datatype='GPFeatureLayer',  # This is key line 1
            parameterType='Required',
            direction='Output')
        param4.value = r'C:\`work\FME\out.gdb\Export_Output'  # This is key line 2
        params.append(param4)

        ...

        return params

    def updateParameters(self, params):
        return
    def updateMessages(self, params):
        return
    def execute(self, params, messages):
        pass
```

The path in key line 2 is set as default value only for me to use, and I barely change it.

If I use 'GPFeatureLayer' in key line 1, everytime I restart arcmap and double-click to open toolbox, it will take time (tens seconds or more) to check if a feature in this path exists[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQw7z.png).

If I ues 'GPString' in key line 1, check[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQw7z.png) won't happen so that the check-time is skipped.

Comment: How many featureclasses exist in `out.gdb`? See if an empty geodatabase speeds things up?

Comment: @Hornbydd there's only 1 feature (Export_Output)